# Are inline static variables unique across modules in visual c++?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, c++17

c++17 introduce inline (static) variables. It is said that

> "The compiler will guarantee that a variable has only one definition
>   and it’s initialised only once through all compilation units."

I am wondering if visual c++ guarantee inline static variable will be unique across multiple modules (dlls and exe).

```
//cat.h
class __declspec(dllexport) Cat
{
public:
    inline static int var = 0;
};
```

If cat.h is included in multiple dlls and one exe, is Cat::var unique in the application ?

Comment: If you have, say, three modules, one exe and two dlls, then there will be three instances of `var` here. I am not aware of any linkage mechanism for PE modules that would allow them to refer to the same memory.

Comment: @camino I would expect it to be unique, the inline keyword is replacing the 'extern', where only one of the modules would actually instantiate the variable as only one of the modules would contain the .cpp. But why dont you just test it?

Comment: Also to the first question: The c++ cannot guarantee anything about dlls as they are strictly windows thing.

Comment: I was curious about the same thing in static libraries and an exe where for example we have a config header used amoung them but only initiated in the exe main function

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite 'open-ended' but, if what you actually want is only one instance, then you should define a macro - say `DLLIMPEXP` - that is conditionally defined as `__declspec(dllexport)` in one module (where the class is actually defined, or at least instantiated) and as `__declspec(dllimport)` in the other two. Then have your header declaration:

```
//cat.h
class DLLIMPEXP Cat
{
public:
    inline static int var = 0;
};
```

Note1: I think the class linkage declaration overrides the member's.
Note2: It doesn't have to be a DLL that exports; EXEs can export too, and DLLs can import!
Note3: As others have said, the C++17 standard does not (cannot) apply across link modules.