# Are function local static objects of inline functions shared across shared object files?

Tags: c++

I have a `inline` function with a function local static defined in a header like so:

`singleton.hpp`

```cpp
inline int& instance(){
   static int v;
   return v;
}
```

I include `header.hpp` into two, independent shared objects `A.so` and `B.so`.

`A.so`:

```cpp
#include "singleton.hpp"

namespace A{

void set(int v){
    instance() = v;
}

int get(){
    return instance();
}

}
```

`B.so`:

```cpp
#include "singleton.hpp"

namespace B{

void set(int v){
    instance() = v;
}

int get(){
    return instance();
}

}
```

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include "a.hpp"
#include "b.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(void){
    A::set(42);
    std::cout << B::get() << std::endl;

    B::set(13);
    std::cout << A::get() << std::endl;
}
```

I link both `A.so` and `B.so` against my executable `main`.

**Question**: Do `A.so` and `B.so` see the same function local static object? 
In other words, if I modify `v` from `A.so` like `instance() = 42`, is that visible from `B.so`?

I actually tried this, and it **does** indeed work. However, I'm not sure if this is some implementation specific or undefined behavior. See https://github.com/jrhemstad/link_test for complete example.

Comment: This is [known to be broken on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57495423/8586227) (and is similarly broken elsewhere with “two-level namespaces” or hidden symbols).  There are practical reasons for the breakage, but the result is not C++.

Comment: Has inline any effect in todays compilers?

Comment: @Klaus Yes, it does. The presence of `inline` in a function declaration means that the function's definition must appear in every translation unit that calls it. *(If you meant to ask about any effect on inlining the function call, then no it does not, and has not since C++ was standardized.)*

Comment: @JaMiT: Oh yes! I forget that the generated code will be "tagged" to allow it is present in multiple generated object files and suppress the linker error. Thanks for the reminder :-)

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of inline in c++ is different from the use in C. See [inline in c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Since c++17 the specs define that for an inline function

> Function-local static objects in all function definitions are shared across all translation units (they all refer to the same object defined in one translation unit)

For pure "inline" this works but with "static inline" at least g++ still creates multiple copies of the static objects.

Comment: The question was about if the notion of "translation units" extends across dynamic libraries being linked together and if they will share the same definition of a function local static. The standard doesn't say anything about dynamic linking, so strictly speaking, I believe this is implementation defined behavior.

Comment: Good point about extending this across dynamic libraries. But it's still just building a binary out of translation units even if it's done at program start. The magic used in .o files for marking those inline static variables in ELF files carries over into .so files as they are basically the same. And then the dynamic linker seems to resolve them the same way the static linker does, which is why it works under Linux. I would call that c++ standard conform.

Comment: Note that for real libraries this is probably not the desired behavior and they should change the visibility of inline static variables and functions so this can't happen.