# Sharing global config variables between executable and static libraries via headers using namespace and inline static members

Tags: c++, c++17, static-libraries, executable

Im trying to share some common config variables between some of my related static libraries and enabling the variables to be initialized and set within the main function of an executable linking against those libs as an example:

---

**Config.h**

```
#pragma once
class Global_Config {
        public:
            inline static Execution_Mode _Execution_Mode = Execution_Mode::Distributed;

            inline static int Config_Mode = 0;
            inline static std::string THIS_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
            inline static std::string MASTER_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
}
```

which is used by lib1.a and lib2.a and main.cpp(a.out)

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Config.h"
#include "other_lib1.h"
#include "other_lib2.h"

int main()
{
    Global_Config::Config_Mode = 1;
    Global_Config::MASTER_HOST = "192.168.1.1";
    //lib1 related stuff
    //.....
    //lib2 related stuff
    //.....    

    return 0;
}
```

this is a simplified demonstration of my case but my project is a bit more complex, this approach seems to be compiled and linked correctly but I'm getting some undefined behavior which I'm not sure that is related to this approach or some other parts. is this a correct way of implementing this logic? are these config variables unique across  libraries and the main function? I've tried implementing this using variables inside namespace but its getting multiple object definition errors. if the current approach is not correct how could this logic be implemented?

Comment: With undefined behaviour in play you pretty much always need to give a [mre]. At the moment you're basically saying, "My car won't start." and handing the mechanic the steering wheel to examine and troubleshoot.

Comment: @user4581301 I was providing the MASTER_HOST variable to the libs first I had defined the inline static members as const and it was working then I made them this way and now I'm getting an error from third party libs used by lib1 and lib2 that the variable is not a correct ip while I've actually didn't change anything in its value but just making it a non const member

Comment: @AmirRasti Please put all your clarifications in the question. When does the third party library read these global variables? It sounds like it reads them before you change them. Is threading involved? You need to clarify this a lot more. A [mre] would be preferable.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo thanks  , and I've had some issues on what to include that is related but I will do my best to complete the current sample, and about your notes, there is threading included but its only started after the part I commented as lib1 stuff and lib2 stuff also the inline members are accessed only in that interval. I've also found a related question on this but referring to shared libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57495423/are-inline-static-variables-unique-across-modules-in-visual-c

Comment: Making a good example is hard work, but it pays off a couple ways. One it makes it a lot more likely that we can answer the question and two it make it less likely that you need to ask the question at all. The smaller an example, the less room mistakes have to hide, and odds are good a few passes into making the smaller example you've picked the bugs off yourself without any help.

Comment: it's correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515591/c17-inline-variable-vs-inline-static-variable
could you elaborate on "getting some undefined behavior"? what happens?

Comment: Descriptions of your code won't help us much. _Please_ make a [mre] so that we can compile your code and possibly get the same result - or at least be made aware of potential race conditions or static initialization order fiascos.